# PHP echo values outside conditional if

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PHP code:

```
    <?php
    //Connection to PDO Database
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
    <p>Busisness telephone 1</p><input id="business_telephone_01" name="business_telephone_01" tabindex="auto" value="<?php echo $result['business_telephone_01']; ?>" type="text" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes"></form>

    <?php
    //Get from Form

    if((empty($_POST['submit']) === false)){
    $business_telephone_01 = $_POST['business_telephone_01'];
//Formating of telephone numbers
$message = 'This message I want to display';
echo 'This is another message';
      }

echo $message;
    //Code to update table through PDO
?>
```

Regardless of where I do the echo whether it is *echo 'This is another message';* within the conditional brackets or _ echo $message;_ outside the brackets nothing is being echoed and no error is being displayed.

The html form and the PDO are working correctly and are being updated but nothing is being echoed. No error is being shown in the error log.

**UPDATE:**

- If I use `if((empty($_POST['submit']) === false)){` I get  PHP
  Notice:  Undefined variable: hello
- If I use `if    (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` I get  PHP Notice: 
  Undefined variable:    hello
- If I use `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
  {` it gives me a list    of undefined variables that I use e.g. from
  my code above business_telephone_01

**My full code**

```
if((empty($_POST['submit']) === false)){
//Get from Form
        $address_building_name = $_POST['address_building_name'];
        $address_building_number = $_POST['address_building_number'];
        $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
        $address_locality = $_POST['address_locality'];
        $address_postcode = $_POST['address_postcode'];
        $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];

//Formating of address
        $address_building_number = strtoupper($address_building_number);
        $address_building_number = str_replace(' ','',$address_building_number);
        $address_building_name = ucwords($address_building_name);
        $address_street = ucwords($address_street);
        $address_locality = ucwords($address_locality);
        $address_postcode = strtoupper($address_postcode);
        $address_country = ucwords($address_country);

        echo 'Hello';
        $good = 'Good bye';

    } 
    echo $good;
```

Comment: Why not simply use **if($_POST['submit']){**? Also, are there any errors on submit?

Comment: @dwhite.me 'cause that'll emit a warning if `$_POST['submit']` doesn'T exist.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can turn these messages off. You should use isset($_POST['submit']) then.

Comment: And as I wrote this an answer from @leng exactly as I meant popped up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be willing to bet `$message` isn't being echo'd because it's never initialized.  (The `if` block, where it is supposed to be initialized, is not being executed because the conditional is failing.)

First off, you should use `isset` to determine if a POST variable has been submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Or, to see if it has *not* been submitted:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Secondly, you should enable error reporting on your program and let us know what errors (if any) you are getting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

You can add these two lines to the very top of your script, right after the opening `<?php` line, which should help shed some light on the situation.

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` in your first line of code.

Comment: @Leng first of all thank you for your help, but I tried your methods but I got errors please see the update to my question, please.

Comment: @user Then get rid of the error - deal with the undefined hello variable.  Or show us your code if you're lost.

Comment: @Leng I updated my code in the question above - i am currently experimenting with the above. The echos are not dispaying. I get the following error  Undefined variable: good

Comment: @user Dude - you're still using the ridiculous `if` condition, so you're never going to execute that block until you fix it.

Comment: @user Empty can't be used the way you're using it.  Change it to `isset`.

Comment: @user Read this article:  http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the $message variable is never set within your if statement.
If the 'if' condition is not matched, then $message is never set and you will not be able to echo the value.

To test, you could set the $message variable to some value before you start your if statement.

```
$message = 'condition failed';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
....
$message = 'This message I want to display';
}
echo $message;
```

If the condition is met, it will echo "This message I want to display".
If the condition fails, it will echo 'condition failed';

A quick dirty test, but it will tell you if the $message variable will be initialized inside your 'if' statement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am going to use it :-)